# Merging of multiple tables with Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, merge, union

On work, I have a problem with merging multiple tables into one table with Microsoft Access. So what I have is one Microsoft Access DB-file with multiple tables.

We can assume that each table only consists out of two columns. CustomerID and numb_of_purchases. I have one table for each month and want to merge all those tables in one big table, so for example for two months:

```
TableJan
    Customer_ID  numb_of_purchases_Jan
    1                     10
    2                     53
    3                     98
    4                     101
```

and

```
TableFeb
    Customer_ID  numb_of_purchases_Feb
    3                     86
    5                     5
```

are supposed to be merged into a bigger table, which looks like:

```
  Customer_ID  numb_of_purchases_Jan  numb_of_Purchases_Feb
    1                     10                   0
    2                     53                   0
    3                     98                   86
    4                     101                  0
    5                     0                    5
```

---

how would you solve such a problem? At first I thought it would be very easy by, for example, using the UNION function, so I tried to write the following query:

```
SELECT TableJan.Customer_ID, numb_of_purchases_Jan
FROM Table_Jan

UNION

SELECT TableFeb.Customer_ID, numb_of_purchases_Feb
FROM Table_Feb;
```

Executing this query was something along these lines:

```
Customer_ID  numb_of_purchases_Jan
1                     10
1                     0
2                     53
2                     0
3                     98
3                     86
4                     101
4                     0
5                     5
```

So essentially, I am missing an entire column compared to the desired output and instead the values of numb_of_purchases_Feb are stored in the numb_of_purchases_Jan-column.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point out any mistakes in my UNION-command or have an other, maybe more simpler solution to the given problem.

Comment: Your question perfectly illustrates the problems arising with not norrmalized database. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics

Comment: Oh...I see you never marked your previous questions as answered. Please fix that, to show some respect for those who try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION is to give rows combined on same no of columns and types.

As your o/p contains no of columns different from that of your input hence, you need to use Join

```
   SELECT a.Customer_ID, 
      a.numb_of_purchases_Jan,
      b.numb_of_purchases_FEB
     FROM TABLE_JAN a LEFT 
    JOIN TABLE_FEB b on 
     a.Customer_ID=b.Customer_ID
```

Comment: `JOIN` is indeed the way to go here, but since MS Access does not support `full outer join`, you need to `UNION` a `RIGHT JOIN` to your `LEFT JOIN`, in case we have new customers in FEB.

Comment: EDIT: Ah, Patrick was faster. Does any of you have an example code for using Union to combine the Right Join and Left Join?



Ah, true. Makes sense that UNION didn't work. But with a Left Join I would be missing the Customer_IDs of the people that only bought in February and didn't buy in January, right? Because that's what I would like to see.

I thought of using Full Join for that, because that would give me the full Customer_ID-list but Access doesn't support full joins it seems.

Answer (score 0):

@Himanshu provided a good start of reply to your question.  But the design you requested is inefficient in my opinion. I would rather use something like:

```
SELECT TableJan.Customer_ID, numb_of_purchases_Jan as numb_of_purchases, #1/1/2019# as Period 
FROM Table_Jan 
UNION ALL 
SELECT TableFeb.Customer_ID, numb_of_purchases_Feb as numb_of_purchases, #2/1/2019# as Period 
FROM Table_Feb;
```

You would then end up with a 3 fields dataset:

- CustomerID
- numb_of_purchases
- period

from which your can easily calculate Monthly, Quarterly, Yearly sales....

Do you have any good reason to denormalize ? Millions of rows ?

Comment: Thank you. I will try your suggestions tomorrow and let you know about the results. Regarding not having normalized tables: There aren't any reasons, I just have the datasets at hand and have to work with them. I don't have access to the core database.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access doesn't support full outer join.  But you might be able to use `union all` and `group by`:

```
SELECT Customer_ID,
      SUM(numb_of_purchases_Jan) as numb_of_purchases_Jan,
      SUM(numb_of_purchases_Feb) as numb_of_purchases_Feb
FROM (SELECT TableJan.Customer_ID, numb_of_purchases_Jan, 0 as numb_of_purchases_Feb
      FROM Table_Jan 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT TableFeb.Customer_ID, 0, numb_of_purchases_Feb 
      FROM Table_Feb 
     ) c
GROUP BY Customer_ID
ORDER BY Customer_ID;
```

Then, you should fix your data processing.  There is no reason to store the same information in tables that have the same structure.  All this data should be in a single table, with an additional column that specifies the time period.